# I have a problem with displaying username. It outputs to the database, but not to the application itself

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUBvu.png)
I recently started learning Java and decided to create an application. When registering, it shows the username in my database, but not in the application itself.I thought I had a problem with id but, no, everything is correct there. I've been looking for the second day and I just can't figure out what the problem is. Thanks in advance for solving the problem. What is the problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser mUser;
    DatabaseReference mUserRef, PostRef, LikeRef, commentRef;
    String profileImageUrlV, usernameV;
    CircleImageView profileImageHeader;
    TextView username_header;
    ImageView addImagePost, sendImagePost;
    EditText inputPostDesc;
    Uri imageUri;
    ProgressDialog mLoadingBar;
    StorageReference postImageRef;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, MyViewHolder> adapter;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Comment> CommentOption;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentViewHolder> CommentAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        addImagePost = findViewById(R.id.addimagePost);
        sendImagePost = findViewById(R.id.send_post_imageView);
        inputPostDesc = findViewById(R.id.inputAddPost);
        mLoadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        PostRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
        LikeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
        commentRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments");
        postImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("PostImages");


        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navView);

        View view = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.drawer_header);
        profileImageHeader = view.findViewById(R.id.profileImage_header);
        username_header = view.findViewById(R.id.username_header);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        sendImagePost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddPost();
            }
        });
        addImagePost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        });
        LoadPost();
    }

    private void LoadPost()
    {
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>().setQuery(PostRef, Posts.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, MyViewHolder>(options)
        {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Posts model) {
                final String postKey = getRef(position).getKey();
                holder.postDesc.setText(model.getPostDesc());
                String timeAgo = calculateTimeAgo(model.getDatePost());
                holder.timeAgo.setText(timeAgo);
                holder.username.setText(model.getUsername());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getPostImageUrl()).into(holder.postImage);
                Picasso.get().load(model.getUserProfileImageUrl()).into(holder.profileImage);
                holder.countLikes(postKey, mUser.getUid(), LikeRef);
                holder.countComments(postKey, mUser.getUid(), commentRef);
                holder.likeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        LikeRef.child(postKey).child(mUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                    LikeRef.child(postKey).child(mUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                                    holder.likeImage.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY);
                                } else {
                                    LikeRef.child(postKey).child(mUser.getUid()).setValue("Like");
                                    holder.likeImage.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN);
                                }
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                holder.commentSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String comment = holder.inputComments.getText().toString();
                        if (comment.isEmpty()) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please write something in EditText", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            AddComment(holder, postKey, commentRef, mUser.getUid(), comment);
                        }
                    }
                });
                LoadComment(postKey);

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_view_post, parent, false);
                return new MyViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void LoadComment(String postKey) {
        MyViewHolder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        CommentOption = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Comment>().setQuery(commentRef.child(postKey), Comment.class).build();
        CommentAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentViewHolder>(CommentOption) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CommentViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Comment model) {
                Picasso.get().load(model.getProfileImageUrl()).into(holder.profileImage);
                holder.username.setText(model.getUsername());
                holder.comment.setText(model.getComment());

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public CommentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_view_comment, parent, false);
                return new CommentViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        CommentAdapter.startListening();
        MyViewHolder.recyclerView.setAdapter(CommentAdapter);
    }

    private void AddComment(MyViewHolder holder, String postKey, DatabaseReference commentRef, String uid, String comment) {
        HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
        hashMap.put("username", usernameV);
        hashMap.put("profileImageUrl", profileImageUrlV);
        hashMap.put("comment", comment);

        commentRef.child(postKey).child(uid).updateChildren(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Comment Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    holder.inputComments.setText(null);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private String calculateTimeAgo(String datePost) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        try {
            long time = sdf.parse(datePost).getTime();
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            CharSequence ago =
                    DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
            return ago + "";
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            addImagePost.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }

    private void AddPost() {
        String postDesc = inputPostDesc.getText().toString();
        if (postDesc.isEmpty() || postDesc.length() < 1) {
            inputPostDesc.setError("Please write something in post");
        } else if (imageUri == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            mLoadingBar.setTitle("Твой пост добавляется пожалуйста потерпи немного)");
            mLoadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            mLoadingBar.show();

            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            String strDate = formatter.format(date);

            postImageRef.child(mUser.getUid() + strDate).putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        postImageRef.child(mUser.getUid() + strDate).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {


                                HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
                                hashMap.put("datePost", strDate);
                                hashMap.put("postImageUrl", uri.toString());
                                hashMap.put("postDesc", postDesc);
                                hashMap.put("userProfileImageUrl", profileImageUrlV);
                                hashMap.put("username", usernameV);
                                PostRef.child(mUser.getUid() + strDate).updateChildren(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            mLoadingBar.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Пост добавлен)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            addImagePost.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_post_image);
                                            inputPostDesc.setText("");
                                        } else {
                                            mLoadingBar.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        mLoadingBar.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mUser == null) {
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        } else {
            mUserRef.child(mUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        profileImageUrlV = dataSnapshot.child("profileImage").getValue().toString();
                        usernameV = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                        Picasso.get().load(profileImageUrlV).into(profileImageHeader);
                        username_header.setText(usernameV);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!, Something going wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.profile:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                break;

            case R.id.friend:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Friend", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.find_friend:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FindFriendActivity.class));
                break;

            case R.id.chat:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Chat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.Logout:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the database hierarchy .. also what happens when you run the app, do you get any errors;; does the app runs but the username is not shown?

Comment: Yes second variant. The problem is when I start the application it starts the application starts without errors.

Comment: Do you go to login page .. and enter the username and password, and go further beyond in your app when the credentials are OK?

Comment: Everything logs in and registers for me, but only I have an Activity where the username should be written, that's where it doesn’t display username

Comment: Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yeah  I got you . can you share database hierarchy on Firebase

Comment: It can not be explained in a comment .. please see https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Basic_Firebase_Realtime_Database_Tutorial

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}

Comment: We need to see a photo like https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/File:Firebase_database_example_tree_1.png

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: I realize I created a question of over 400 lines of code, just if I figured out where the error is and how to fix it, I would post one part, but I don't know what the problem is because of this. But thanks for the advice, I'll think about it next time.

Comment: my-app5-df283-default-rtdb 



"Comments g3r0EMxmaJOGVGuu9lfmUCRNBbk113-1-2021 01:49:57" 



" Likes g3r0EMxmaJOGVGuu9lfmUCRNBbk113-1-2021 01:49:57"



" Posts g3r0EMxmaJOGVGuu9lfmUCRNBbk113-1-2021 01:49:57"



" User g3r0EMxmaJOGVGuu9lfmUCRNBbk1"

Comment: I think it will be clear, I just don't know how to insert a photo here, and in general is it possible?

Comment: @ДжамильАгаев You should check you model class (Posts.java). May be you mistyped. ```username``` or ```Username``` if ```u``` is capital then change to small

Comment: I checked my Post. Java is written with a small letter username.I thought that I should write big. But it still does not work, both with small and large

Comment: @ДжамильАгаев If you add an image of the database in question. That would be easy for us to answer.

Comment: I added an image of the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
```

with

```
mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
```

Child name should be same